# Unable to add date into mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named user_analytics. I created it by the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE user_analytics(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> active INT NOT NULL,
    -> suspended INT NOT NULL,
    -> deactivated INT NOT NULL,
    -> date DATE NOT NULL
    -> );
```

Now i'm inserting value in this date, but unable to add today's date. This is how i'm doing it:

```
$active = 1000;
$suspended = 33;
$deactivated = 5;
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO user_analytics VALUES('', $active, $suspended, $deactivated, $date)";

$sql_insert_query = mysql_query($sql_insert);
```

The date column always saves date as 0000-00-00

Comment: What is $sql_insert? And put quotes around $date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with quotes on your query variables

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO user_analytics VALUES('', '$active', '$suspended', '$deactivated', '$date')";

$sql_insert_query = mysql_query($sql_insert);
```

**Note**:- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`